# DB table extract and linking extracted data

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

let's assume we've got following tables in DB:

```
CREATE TABLE #nodes(reporter varchar(10), groupname varchar(10), node varchar(20))
CREATE TABLE #nodes_extract(id int IDENTITY, min_node varchar(20), count_nodes int, descr varchar(10) );
CREATE TABLE #nodes_histo(reporter varchar(10), groupname varchar(10), node varchar(20), nodes_extract_id int)
```

Example of data:

```
INSERT INTO #nodes (reporter, groupname, node) VALUES ('rep1','group1','node1')
INSERT INTO #nodes (reporter, groupname, node) VALUES ('rep1','group1','node2')
INSERT INTO #nodes (reporter, groupname, node) VALUES ('rep1','group2','node3')
INSERT INTO #nodes (reporter, groupname, node) VALUES ('rep2','group1','node1')
INSERT INTO #nodes (reporter, groupname, node) VALUES ('rep2','group1','node4')
INSERT INTO #nodes (reporter, groupname, node) VALUES ('rep2','group2','node5')
INSERT INTO #nodes (reporter, groupname, node) VALUES ('rep3','group1','node5')
INSERT INTO #nodes (reporter, groupname, node) VALUES ('rep3','group1','node6')
INSERT INTO #nodes (reporter, groupname, node) VALUES ('rep3','group2','node7')
```

Let's extract some data into #nodes_extract

```
INSERT INTO #nodes_extract
SELECT min(node), count(node), 'blabla'
FROM #nodes
GROUP BY reporter, groupname
```

Now I would like insert all information from #nodes to #nodes_histo and add nodes_extract_id
Expected result in #nodes_histo:

```
    reporter    groupname   node    nodes_extract_id
    rep1        group1      node1   1
    rep1        group1      node2   1
    rep1        group2      node3   4
    rep2        group1      node1   2
    rep2        group1      node4   2
    rep2        group2      node5   5
    rep3        group1      node5   3
    rep3        group1      node6   3
    rep3        group2      node7   6
```

How would you achieve the goal?
Is it possible without changing tables structure?

thanks a lot!
kafe

Comment: Can you please explain how that number `nodes_extract_id` is evaluated from the values of `reporter`, `groupname` and `node`?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: it's just an autoincremental ID from extract table..

Comment: OK, but there are no nodes `node2`, `node4` and `node6` in the table `#nodes_extract`, therefore they had no auto increment ids. How do you want to insert ids for them into the `#nodes_histo` table? Or, why they should be given the ids that you showed in the desired result `1`, `2` and `3` respectively?

Comment: OK, I'll try to explain on a different example. Let's say table #nodes contains some questions. Some of them could be answered by the same answer. Nodes_extract table contains the answers. It's created based on key words from #nodes table, but I don't want to insert keywords to #extract table. So I just would like to point to particular answer.

Comment: So what about those questions that had no answers in the nodes_extract? what would the id for them?

Comment: since answers are built based on the groups of questions, there is no option to get not answered questions..

Comment: OK, here is my attempt: `INSERT INTO nodes_histo
SELECT 
  n.reporter,
  n.groupname,
  n.node,
  (SELECT MIN(e.Id) 
   FROM nodes_extract AS e
   WHERE e.min_node = n.node) AS nodes_extract_id
FROM nodes AS n;` Like [**in this live demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05d1a/1), but as I said, it will give you `NULL`'s for `node2`, `node4` and `node6` since they have no entries in the other table. I thought this might be helpful for you.

Comment: thank you Mahmoud, I think I found the solution..Basicaly the mistake is to insert values to extract table without `distinct`. So I fix that and my solution is: `SELECT a.reporter, a.groupname,a.node, e.id 
FROM 
 (SELECT  reporter
   , groupname
   , node
   , min(node) OVER (PARTITION BY REPORTER, groupname) m
   , count(node) OVER (PARTITION BY REPORTER, groupname) c
 FROM #nodes) a
LEFT JOIN 
 #nodes_extract e
ON a.m = e.min_node
AND a.c = e.count_nodes`  Here is the solution [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01386/1/0)

Comment: If this query is what worked for you, add it as an answer and accept this answer. This how things work here in Stackoverflow. And welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, I will do that, but _Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.._ so I will answer in 3 hours ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think I found a way..

First of all `DISTINCT` is required in the insert command:

```
INSERT INTO #nodes_extract
SELECT DISTINCT min(node), count(node), 'blabla'
FROM #nodes
GROUP BY reporter, groupname
```

And with following select I can extract information I'm looking for:

```
INSERT INTO #nodes_histo
SELECT a.reporter, a.groupname,a.node, e.id 
FROM 
    (SELECT  reporter
            , groupname
            , node
            , min(node) OVER (PARTITION BY REPORTER, groupname) m
            , count(node) OVER (PARTITION BY REPORTER, groupname) c
    FROM #nodes) a
LEFT JOIN 
    #nodes_extract e
ON a.m = e.min_node
AND a.c = e.count_nodes
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you would have to include a way to join the tables, probably by including reporter and groupname in #nodes_extract.  Even if you were to try to regenerate #nodes_extract with the same query (and the additional columns), there's no guarantee that the order would be the same.